# Omission of curly braces for a hash in an array

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I realized that the curly braces for a hash can be omitted if it is the last element in an array. For example, the forms:

```
[1, 2, 3, :a => 'A', :b => 'B']
[1, 2, 3, a: 'A', b: 'B']
```

seem to be identical to:

```
[1, 2, 3, {:a => 'A', :b => 'B'}]
[1, 2, 3, {a: 'A', b: 'B'}]
```

I knew this kind of omission is possible for arguments of a method, but had not noted it is possible for an array. Is my understanding of this rule correct? And, is this described somewhere?

Comment: I suppose that in theory, `[...]` is a method call to a method that looks like `def x(*args)` so the behavior makes some sense. Maybe dig up the array literal handling C code to see how it is handled internally.

Comment: I wouldn't use it as a coding practice though. I prefer seeing the visual delimiting provided by `{` and `}`, and would state that in a code review. It's a maintenance and readability issue.

Comment: @muistooshort It works even if it is not a method call. This works for just creating an array.

Comment: @theTinMan It should depend on the situation. I have a DSL, in which things are written using nested arrays and hashes. At the end of each array, some of the object to be specirfied with that part of the array can have its properties specified by a hash, and it is so frequent that if this omission is possible, it makes a huge difference.

Comment: You misunderstand what I'm saying. `[1,2,3,:a => 'b']` is, in some sense, a method call to an array constructor method so of course it behaves like every other method call and auto-hashifies its arguments.

Comment: I can tell you that it does not work in 1.8.6 or 1.8.7, but does in 1.9.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would seem to be a new feature of 1.9:

```
$ rvm use 1.8.7
$ irb
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :001 > x = [ 1,2,3,:a => 4, :b => 5 ]
SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):1: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting ']'
x = [ 1,2,3,:a => 4, :b => 5 ]
                 ^
  from (irb):1
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :002 > exit
$ rvm use 1.9.3
$ irb
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :001 > x = [ 1,2,3,:a => 4, :b => 5 ]
 => [1, 2, 3, {:a=>4, :b=>5}] 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :002 >
```

Comment: Note that cases where the array contains only hashes do work in 1.8.x:
```ruby
1.8.6-p420 :001 > x = [ :a => 4, :b => 5 ]
 => [{:a=>4, :b=>5}]
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the brackets (and no brackets, like below) are called hash literals and ruby just tries to fit it as an array element.

```
>> [1, 2, c: 'd', e: 'f'] # ruby 1.9 hash literals
=> [1, 2, {:c=>"d", :e=>"f"}]
```

But there aren't more rules to it, I think - you can't do this:

```
>> [1, 2, c: 'd', e: 'f', 5] # syntax error, unexpected `]` (waiting for => or :)
```

Comment: The type that is returned isn't a Hash, but an Array, so it's an Array literal with an embedded Hash literal

Comment: yes, that's right. were you hoping for a hash literal like this: `a: b, c: d`?